# Button will be locked until radiobutton, textbox, checkbox and combo box is ticked

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, button

I know this might be simple for most of you but I need help.

btnBuild shouldn't be clickable until the textbox1 have been filled out, radio button, check box and combo box have an item that is selected. And when the btnReset is clicked the btnBuild will return on being not clickable since all the field will be cleared. I already have a code for the btnReset, only the btnBuild being unclickable is my problem.

grpBx1 contains 4 radiobuttons, grpBx2 contains 3 radiobuttons, grpBx3 contains 4 checkboxes and then the 2 combo boxes doesn't belong to any groupbox

Comment: Are all the RadioButtons in the same container?  How about the CheckBoxes? What are the names of these controls?

Comment: Hello yes, radio buttons are on a group box, same with check box, only the two combo box are not group

Comment: grpBx1 contains 4 radiobuttons, grpBx2 contains 3 radiobuttons, grpBx3 contains 4 checkboxes and then the 2 combo boxes doesn't belong to any groupbox

Comment: You can definitely extend my solution below to handle this. Make a List for each SET of RadioButtons, then add in checks for the ComboBoxes as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an event modified for every mandatory field and do something like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
        {
            btnBuild.enable =false;
        }
```

Why use event 'modified'? Because each time the content of a field changes, you want to make sure there's still something in there. Then if it's empty, disable btnBuild. Could also use an error provider. Keep also in mind that a textEdit item, uses the '.Text' property to check if it has a value, whereas a DateEdit item, needs the '.EditValue', sp find the apropriate property for each different item you use. It would also be helpfull to post the btnReset code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the bottom of your btnReset click event.

```
btnBuild.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it. Build up Lists to hold a collection of both your RadioButtons and CheckBoxes so that you can easily determine if any of them are checked as well as use those same Lists to reset them.  Then make a single method that determines if `btnBuild` should be enabled or not. Simply change the controls listed in both `CBs` and `RBs`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<CheckBox> CBs;
    private List<RadioButton> RBs;
    
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnBuild.Enabled = false;
        CBs = new List<CheckBox> { checkBox1, checkBox2, checkBox3};
        RBs = new List<RadioButton> { radioButton1, radioButton2, radioButton3 };
        CBs.ForEach(cb =>
        {
            cb.CheckedChanged += (s2, e2) => updateBuildButton();
        });
        RBs.ForEach(rb =>
        {
            rb.CheckedChanged += (s2, e2) => updateBuildButton();
        });
        textBox1.TextChanged += (s2, e2) => updateBuildButton();

        btnReset.PerformClick();
    }

    private void updateBuildButton()
    {
        bool cbChecked = CBs.Any(cb => cb.Checked);
        bool rbSelected = RBs.Any(rb => rb.Checked);
        bool tbPopulated = textBox1.Text.Trim().Length > 0;
        btnBuild.Enabled = cbChecked && rbSelected && tbPopulated;
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        CBs.ForEach(cb => cb.Checked = false);
        RBs.ForEach(rb => rb.Checked = false);
    }

}
```